# How to link a module in an app by npm link

Tags: npm-link

I have a library, let's call it my_library, that I need to link it to my app. So what I've done so far is:

**1. In my_library directory:**

```
#install dependencies
npm install  
cd projects/my_library
npm install
```

projects/my_library/node_modules is created, then build:

```
cd ../..
ng build
```

dist/my_library is created, then: `cd dist/my_library`

then link build to the local npm: `npm link`

**2. Link library to app**

In app directory:

```
npm link my_library
```

But `npm link my_library` gives the error:

```
mpm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/my_library - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'my_library@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

Does anyone know why this error is shown and how I can solve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just noticed that my library has a different node version than my app
(my_library `v14.20` and my app `v14.15`).

So the symlink of my_library was in `/home/../.nvm/versions/node/v14.20.1/lib/node_modules/my_library`. I guess my app is not looking in the correct directory (maybe is looking in `v.14.15.1`). So I used the same node version as of my_library for my app (i.e.,`v14.20`) and then the problem was solved!